# Create a bias for a range of numbers within a larger range

Tags: python

Using Python, I'm trying to create a program that randomly picks a float between 0 and 359.9. I wanted to be able to specify a bias for a range within those numbers. This might look like a function that takes 3 floats as arguments. The first two arguments would serve as the lower and upper bounds for my biased range. The third would be the probability that a number from that range would be picked. Beyond very basic usage of the random module, my knowledge in this area and in statistics in general is lacking. So I'm open to the possibility that a function may not be the best way to go about this, and grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: You should define your problem more formally, which will make it easier to formulate it as code as well. What have you tried at all? Please share code of your attempts, so people can see what exactly you're having trouble with and how much of explanation is needed for a solution. If I call your function `f` as `f(90, 180, 0.5)` - does that mean there's 50% chance that I get a random value `a` where  `90<=a<180` and and 50% chance I get a random value `0<=a<90 or 180<=a<360`? The odds of getting any value in either (split) range being equal for all values? Does this extend to more bias ranges?

Comment: Why 359.9? Wouldn't the interval [0, 360) be better?

Comment: @Grismar I wasn't too pleased of not being able to include any code in my first post here. But unfortunately I don't know where to begin with this problem so I have no code. Although I could have at least written what the function title would look like so my apologies. Your example is what I had in mind. You would enter the 0.5 probability and and half the time a number from within that range would appear. For now I was just trying to solve the problem of how to do this with one range. Although it is likely that eventually I'd want to define multiple biased ranges.

Comment: @Kelly Bundy in this case it needs to be just below 360 since I'm the object is circular and so 0 occupies the same space as the 360 value.

Comment: @Chiquinho333 That's what Kelly Bundy was suggesting. Instead of stopping arbitrarily at 359.9, [0, 360) means "from 0 to 360, including 0 but excluding 360". For instance, it would include 359.95, which your version would exclude.

Comment: @CrazyChucky Ha! Good point.

Answer (score 1):

With something like this, I'd like a generic solution. I'm assuming:

- biased ranges don't overlap, i.e. it makes little sense to have `(90, 270, 0.6)` as well as `(180, 360, 0.4)`; unless you'd want that to mean the same as `[(90, 180, 0.3), (180, 270, 0.3 + 0.2), (180, 360, 0.2)`, in which case you can either create a function to simplify it for you, or just provide it like that.
- in this case you want values in a degrees range of [0, 360), but in other cases you might want values in the range [0, 24) (hours), or [0, 60) (minutes), etc.
- the summed chances for all bias ranges should add up to <= 1

My approach is to first use a random value to select what range the value comes  from, and then either generate a random value in that range, or if no range was selected, to generate a random value in the combined remaining range(s). To be able to do the last, a random value can be generated in the range [0, scale-sum(other ranges)). By iterating over the bias ranges, check if the value falls before the current range and return it, or add the size of the current range to skip it and repeat.

The code:

```
from random import random
from typing import List, Tuple


def biased_random(bias: List[Tuple[float, float, float]], scale: float = 1) -> float:
    """
    Returns a float in the range [0.0, scale), but accepts a
    sorted list of biases of the form ([start, end), chance), where the sum of
    all chance values should be <= 1, and no interval [start, end) overlaps
    :param bias: list of 3-tuples indicating ([start, end), chance) for a bias
    :param scale: high end of the biased_random function, [0, scale)
    :return: random float in the range [0.0, scale) applying bias
    """
    assert sum(b[2] for b in bias) <= 1, \
        'total bias chance cannot exceed 1'
    assert all(0 <= b[0] < scale and b[0] <= b[1] < scale for b in bias), \
        'every interval is in range [0, scale)'
    assert all(b[0] <= b[1] for b in bias), \
        'every interval is positive length'
    assert all(b1[1] <= b2[0] for b1, b2 in zip(bias, bias[1:])), \
        'intervals are sorted with no overlaps'

    select = random()
    for b in bias:
        if select < b[2]:
            return b[0] + random() * (b[1] - b[0])
        else:
            select -= b[2]
    else:
        result = random() * (scale - sum(b[1] - b[0] for b in bias))
        for b in bias:
            if result < b[0]:
                return result
            else:
                result += b[1] - b[0]
        return result


def main():
    for __ in range(10):
        print(biased_random([(90, 180, 0.5), (180, 270, 0.25)], 360))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Similarly, if you wanted to generate a biased time of day, you could:

```
biased_random([(9, 17, 0.9)], 24)  # 90% chance for a time within work hours
```

Note that you could get rid of the assertions for better performance, if you call this function very frequently (although they wouldn't be checked if you run Python with `-O`). Another solution would be to separate the checks into another function, only check a list of biases once and then reuse it.

Further optimisation could be achieved by creating a function that does all the checks and returns a partial function that has the scale, biases and a precomputed sum of ranges already enclosed, which you can then call for repeated random values with those biases applied.

Something like:

```
from random import random
from typing import List, Tuple, Callable
from functools import partial


def biased_random(bias: List[Tuple[float, float, float]], scale: float = 1, rest_range: float = None) -> float:
    """
    Returns a float in the range [0.0, scale), but accepts a
    sorted list of biases of the form ([start, end), chance), where the sum of
    all chance values should be <= 1, and no interval [start, end) overlaps
    :param bias: list of 3-tuples indicating ([start, end), chance) for a bias
    :param rest_range: the remainder of range outside the bias (scale - sum of ranges)
    :return: random float in the range [0.0, 1.0) applying bias
    """
    select = random()
    if rest_range is None:
        rest_range = scale - sum(b[1] - b[0] for b in bias)
    for b in bias:
        if select < b[2]:
            return b[0] + random() * (b[1] - b[0])
        else:
            select -= b[2]
    else:
        result = random() * rest_range
        for b in bias:
            if result < b[0]:
                return result
            else:
                result += b[1] - b[0]
        return result


def get_biased_random(bias: List[Tuple[float, float, float]], scale: float = 1) -> Callable[[], float]:
    """
    Generate a biased_random function with a checked and set bias and scale
    :param bias: list of 3-tuples indicating ([start, end), chance) for a bias
    :param scale: high end of the biased_random function, [0, scale)
    :return: a biased_random function that will generate a biased value on every call
    """
    assert sum(b[2] for b in bias) <= 1, \
        'total bias chance cannot exceed 1'
    assert all(0 <= b[0] < scale and b[0] <= b[1] < scale for b in bias), \
        'every interval is in range [0, scale)'
    assert all(b[0] <= b[1] for b in bias), \
        'every interval is positive length'
    assert all(b1[1] <= b2[0] for b1, b2 in zip(bias, bias[1:])), \
        'intervals are sorted with no overlaps'

    return partial(biased_random, bias, scale,  scale - sum(b[1] - b[0] for b in bias))


def main():
    biased_random_degrees = get_biased_random([(90, 180, 0.5), (180, 270, 0.25)], 360)
    for __ in range(10):
        print(biased_random_degrees())

    biased_random_time = get_biased_random([(9, 17, 0.9)], 24)
    for __ in range(10):
        print(biased_random_time())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Note that `biased_random` still works as in the first solution, but `get_biased_random` now allows you to generate a checked partial function which you can then call as many times as you like, with the certainty that the enclosed bias and scale are correct, and with the remaining range pre-computed to save time.

Comment: Just a further optimization idea: add the missing ranges, also compute cumulative weights, and then just `return random.uniform(*random.choices(population, weights, cum_weights))`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random


SECTOR_BIAS = {
    (0.0, 59.99999): 0.9,
    (60.0, 119.99999): 0.02,
    (120.0, 179.99999): 0.02,
    (180.0, 239.99999): 0.02,
    (240.0, 299.99999): 0.02,
    (300.0, 359.99999): 0.02,
}

a = []
probability = []

for i in SECTOR_BIAS:
    a.append(i)
    probability.append((SECTOR_BIAS[i]))

n = random.random() * 360
print(n)


def bias(lst, probability):
    zipped = zip(lst, probability)
    lst = [[i[0]] * int(i[1]*100) for i in zipped]
    new = [b for i in lst for b in i]
    return new


biased_list = bias(a, probability)
random_range = random.choice(biased_list)
result = random.randint(int(random_range[0]), int(random_range[1])) + random.random()
print(result)
```

Comment: In the end the code above did. Every range in the target area can have a weight applied to it in the SECTOR BIAS dictionary. In the above example a float from the 0 - 59.9 range has a 90% chance of appearing and all other ranges only a 2% chance.

Comment: So, a value like `299.999995` would never occur, because it is outside both `(240.0, 299.99999)` and `(300.0, 359.99999)`, while chances already add up to 1.0?

Answer (score -1):

There are a couple of ways to achieve such behaviour, the easiest one is probably just to duplicate a number; if you want a probability of ⅓ for option x and ⅔ for y you could use `random.choice([x, y, y])`:
Note: I might be slightly wrong with my probability calculations

```py
# This way there is about twice the chance that the result will be from the biased list than before
# 10%->~19% from the biased (not 20% because we added more items)
def multiply_items(full_range: tuple=(0, 100), biased: tuple=(0, 10), biased_by: float=0.5) -> int:
    l = list(range(full_range[0], full_range[1]))
    l += list(range(biased[0], biased[1])) * int(1 / (1-biased_by) - 1)
    return random.choice(l)
```

*Edit: This is probably the one you're looking for*
Another option is to get a random number between 0-1 and check if it's below the probability, if so choose from the biased, otherwise just choose:

```py
# This way there is 50% more chance that the result will be from the biased range and 50% that it'll be from the full one (which containes the biased range too)
# 10%->50% from the biased
def divided_choice(full_range: tuple=(0, 100), biased: tuple=(0, 10), biased_by: float=0.5) -> int:
    biased_list = range(biased[0], biased[1])
    full_list = range(full_range[0], full_range[1])
    full_list = [x for x in full_list if x not in biased_list]
    if random.random() < biased_by:
        return random.choice(biased_list)
    return random.choice(full_list)
```

Examples:

```py
# 10%->~52%
multiply_items((0, 100), (0, 10), 0.9)
# 10%->25%
multiply_items((0, 100), (0, 10), 0.7)
# 10%->10% (won't change because of rounding, to make it do something you'll need to do more math)
multiply_items((0, 100), (0, 10), 0.2)

# 10%->20%
divided_choice((0, 100), (0, 10), 0.2)
# 10%->70%
divided_choice((0, 100), (0, 10), 0.7)
# 10%->90%
divided_choice((0, 100), (0, 10), 0.9)
```

This is the main idea behind it.